# How to accept command line arguments for files

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {


        File inputFile = null;
        File outputFile = null;


        if (args.length > 0) {
            String inputName = args[0];
            String outputName = args[1];
            inputFile = new File(inputName);
            outputFile = new File(outputName);
        }else{
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            inputFile = new File(input.next());
            outputFile = new File(input.next());
        }

 }
```

this is my code and it's supposed to check the command line arguments for the file name but if there are none it will let the user type the names in. but how do I get it to throw the file not found exception?? i appreciate any help

Comment: I'd use `input.nextLine()` instead of `input.next()` to start with.  You can look at the `File#exists` method to test if a file actually exists

Comment: I'd also consider using `if (args.length == 2) {` or `if (args.length >= 2) {` as it's a better guard around your intent

Comment: `if(true) throw new FileNotFoundException e;`

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using `java.nio.file.Path` over the older `File` class. `java.nio.file.Files` has a lot of utility methods for `Paths`.

You could check if the file exists then throw your own `FileNotFoundException`:

```java
Path path = Path.of(filename);
if (!Files.exists(path)) throw new FileNotFoundException(path.toString());
```

Alternatively you could generate a `NoSuchFileException`:

```java
path.getFileSystem().provider().checkAccess(path);
```